# when i select the time but it showing me today's date when i select time in dropdown how to resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

Example code in given sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-heyrovsky-ys81px?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Replace `timeFormat` to `dateFormat`

```
  <DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    showTimeSelect
    showTimeSelectOnly
    timeIntervals={60}
    timeCaption="Time"
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    dateFormat="HH:mm"
  />
```

AFter update

for 24H use

```
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    dateFormat="HH:mm"
```

Comment: I want 24h time format in both dropdown and date picker

Comment: @Yashporwal check update answer

Answer (score 1):

just pass `DatePicker` props `dateFormat`.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        showTimeSelect
        showTimeSelectOnly
        timeIntervals={60}
        timeCaption="Time"
        timeFormat="HH:mm"
        dateFormat="h:mm aa"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I want 24h time format in both dropdown and date picker

Comment: `dateFormat` just replace with `HH:mm`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateFormat (**dateFormat="h:mm"**) option in the DatePicker.

Comment: but i want 24h time format in dropdown of datepicker

Comment: For 24h format use dateFormat as "HH:mm". For more details you can refer https://reactdatepicker.com/